# Can an external image URL be a security vulnerability?

Tags: html, security

I'm designing a web application and I would like my user to be able to share images. I don't want to store the images on my server. I don't have the space and I don't want to deal with the legal issues. Instead, I want the user to provide me with the URL to an external server.

```
<img src="{URL}" />
```

Now, provided that I escape the URL, its there a chance that the image could inject code into my website, or otherwise cause malicious behavior on users who view the page with that particular image?

Comment: You will not have any problems - the code (if any) will run on the browsers machine. Besides it is not nice to off load traffic to a third party without their permission. Would you like to be done that a person uses your web sites images (graphics) etc without any benefit to them?

Comment: You do realize that you still can be made responsible for the stuff users post in certain countries? Make sure which laws apply for you.